# Origine dell'espressione "Non capire un tubo"

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-origin

L'espressione *non capire un tubo* significa, come ben si sa, non capire niente di un argomento o in senso generale.

A riguardo di [tubo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tubo/) Treccani dice:

> Di uso gergale o fam. (ma di tono volg.) le espressioni *non capire un
>   t., non sapere un t., non me n’importa un t.,* e sim., niente,
>   assolutamente nulla (travestimento eufemistico, in questi casi, di
>   altra parola; cfr. l’analogo uso eufem. di *cavolo*).

La mia domanda/perplessità è su come mai proprio un tubo (visto che c'è l'analogo concetto espresso con il termine "mazza"), da dove trae origine l'utilizzo di tale termine all'interno dell'espressione?

Comment: Giusto un chiarimento. La domanda si riferisce al nesso logico che lega le espressioni c@@@o -> mazza -> tubo all'interno dell'espressione? In tal caso mi sembra abbastanza scontata la risposta, semplicemente per la forma appunto tubolare dei genitali maschili. É piuttosto una domanda su quando é nata l'espressione o su un suo primo uso?

Comment: Soprattutto quando è nata la necessità di sostituire niente con tubo. Ma anche nel caso simile di cavolo in cui l'attinenza con il genitale maschile mi sembra sia meno evidente.

Comment: @abarisone Ho sempre dato per scontanto che "cavolo" venisse da "non capisci un ca.... volo", dove "cavolo" viene sostituito a "cazzo" perché iniziano entrambi allo stesso modo (una tendenza molto comune nelle bestemmie).

Comment: Secondo me è legato alle riparazioni e al lavoro dell' idraulico.  Ma provo ad indovinare. Le tubazioni possono essere intricate pur rimanendo sostanzialmente  semplici. L' idraulica precede la distribuzione di corrente, altrimenti sarebbe potuta nascere (ma più difficilmente) l'espressione non capisci una lampadina/un filo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI21/00000441.jpg) spiega che in questa espressione "tubo" è un eufemismo di "cazzo":

> **6.** Per esprimere la mancanza di valore o d’impor­tanza  di  una  cosa  o  per  rafforzare  la  negazione  di  un fatto  (in  partic.  in  espressioni  come 
>   *Non  capire,  non sentire, non vedere un tubo*; ed è eufem. per *cazzo*).

Nella introduzione a questo vocabolario si spiega che questa opera ha, tra altri, questo obiettivo:

> 3) l’accertamento  della  più  antica  testimonianza in  base  ai  testi  noti,  e  non  soltanto  nei  riguardi  del
>   singolo  termine,  ma  anche  rispetto  ai  vari  significati e  impieghi  che  ne  distinguono  la  diffusione  e  gli sviluppi;

Quindi, è da supporre che il dizionario dà uno dei primi usi dell'espressione in testi letterari in questa citazione tratta dal racconto *L’ora della messa grande* di Beppe Fenoglio

> Anselmino... non perdeva una lezione ma 
>   ce ne capiva un tubo

che nel libro *Beppe Fenoglio. Tutti i racconti*, pubblicato da Einaudi, appare così:

> Non perdeva una lezione ma era chiaro che non ne capiva un tubo.

Non so esattamente quando Fenoglio abbia scritto questo racconto: è stato pubblicato postumo, come molte delle opere di Fenoglio, che morì avendo pubblicato poco. Ma la citazione ci fa vedere che l'espressione cominciò a essere usata prima del 1963, anno della morte di Fenoglio.

Comment: A proposito, se non avete letto i racconti di Fenoglio, vi posso assicurare che, con quelli di Pirandello, sono tra i migliori che si abbiano mai scritto nella lingua italiana. Beh... perlomeno tra quelli che ho letto io.

Answer (score -3):

Secondo me deriva dal francese tohu bohu (confusione , baraonda), che a sua volta deriva dall' ebraico thou va bohu termine che indica il caos primordiale (veci Genesi)